# Python pandas Creating pickle files from a dataframe every time a column difference is greater than 5

Tags: python, pandas

Creating pickle file from the point where difference is higher than 5 to the next 7000 rows and repeating for each time the difference is greater than 5.

For example, I need to create pickle files everytime I pressurize a vessel. The length of the pickle file is a set number of rows that I know(7000 every time). And the way to identify the starting point(when I pressurize) is to see when the pressure change is higher than a certain number. In this case, I would use 5psi.

The way im trying but failing is:

```
if df['pressure change'] >= 5:
    Runs = Runs + 1
    rundf = df.ix[df.loc(df['pressure change']>=5): df.loc(df['pressure change']>=5) + 7000]
    rundf.to_pickle("Run" + str(runs) + ".pkl")
```

Update:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Pressure Change'] >= 4.5:
        runs = runs + 1
        changedRow = df.index[row['Pressure Change'] >= 4.5]
        print changedRow
        rundf = df.ix[changedRow(changedRow+pd.Timedelta(seconds=7250/4))]
        title = str(filename)  + "run" + str(runs) + ".pkl"
        rundf.to_pickle(title)
```

The output is: 
    `2018-01-19 13:58:19.208840
    2018-01-19 13:58:19.208840
    2018-01-19 13:58:19.208840
    2018-01-19 13:58:19.208840`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you provide a sample of your dataframe? Also, what error message do you get?

Comment: dataframe looks like this:

Date, Pressure, Pressure Change
01/22/2018 18:59:05, 0, 0 
01/22/2018 18:59:06, 5, 5
01/22/2018 18:59:07, 5, 0

Comment: OK, and your error message?

Comment: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all(). Sorry, I don't really know the comment formatting of this site yet.

Comment: You are comparing series `df['pressure change']` with an integer 5. The result will be a Boolean series. if statements in python require a True or False result, not a Boolean series.

Comment: hmm, ok so I don't quite understand. How should I change my code?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question right, you should iterate over the rows:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Pressure Change'] >= 5:
        Runs = Runs + 1
        changedRow = df.index[row['Pressure Change'] >= 5]
        rundf = df.loc[changedRow:(changedRow+7000)]
        rundf.to_pickle("Run" + str(runs) + ".pkl")
```

Comment: I'm getting KeyError: True, referring to this line:
   
    `rundf = df.ix[df.loc(df['pressure change']>=5): df.loc(df['pressure change']>=5) + 7000]`

Comment: @Simplystupid I've modified the answer, this should work

Comment: New error:
`ValueError: Cannot add integral value to Timestamp without offset.`

Comment: I believe the reason is because the changedRow is outputting a dateTime value and not a row number, so adding 7000 to it isn't valid.

Comment: So I fixed that, however, it is creating duplicates of the same file, meaning the changedRow is outputting only one row, not every row in which this situation occurs. Any ideas?

Comment: could you post your new code and some rows as example?

Comment: I've updated the post to add the current code I have

Comment: i think that the problem in your code is that you dont select the range of rows that you want to save: rundf = df.ix[changedRow(changedRow+pd.Timedelta(seconds=7250/4))] should be modified. Try with:rundf = df.loc[changedRow:(changedRow+pd.Timedelta(seconds=7250/4))]

Comment: It is not very clear the original dataframe, maybe the code should be:
firstRow = df.index[row['Pressure Change'] >= 4.5]
lastRow =df.ix[changedRow(changedRow+pd.Timedelta(seconds=7250/4))]
rundf = df.loc[firstRow:lastRow]